# How is this a valid ruby statement?

Tags: ruby

```
???? : ??
```

I was recently in a ruby meetup and this statement was posted as a valid ruby statement. Could someone explain its validity and if possible the versions in which it's valid.

Comment: This one is not valid, but maybe it isn't _exactly_ what was shown at that meetup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is likely you are missing a single question mark before the colon: (the white space in not needed however this better mimics your original post)

```
????? : ??
```

The above is valid ruby because the interpreter recognizes this statement as:

```
?? ? ?? : ??
```

This makes use of the the character literal notation:

> character literal notation to represent single character strings, which syntax is a question mark (?) followed by a single character or escape sequence that corresponds to a single codepoint in the script encoding

As well as ternary if `[condition] ? true : false`

Since every object other than `NilClass` or `FalseClass`, is considered "truthy" in ruby, the proposed statement breaks down as :

```
????? : ??
"?" ? "?" : "?"
true ? "?" : "?" 
"?"
```

*This will warn about a string literal in a condition because the else branch is unreachable*

As for "...the versions in which it's valid" . This syntax appears to have always been valid (*although I only tested back to 1.8.7 (2008)*). That being said the result you experience today came about in 1.9.

In 1.8.7 the same statement will return `63` the ASCII decimal code point for question mark.

Answer (score 3):

This variation is valid: (and the one you've seen probably works likewise)

```
????::??
```

It's interpreted as:

```
?? ? ?: : ??
```

With `??` and `?:` being (rarely used) [string literals](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Strings) and `?` / `:` being the [ternary operator](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-Ternary+if).

It's the same as:

```
if '?'
  ':'
else
  '?'
end
```

Out of context, it doesn't do anything useful.

Comment: This is also super valid. Similar explanation as the accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

> I was recently in a ruby meetup and this statement was posted as a valid ruby statement.

The fact that it was posted as valid doesn't make it so.

> Could someone explain its validity

It isn't.

> and if possible the versions in which it's valid.

None.